# How to save user uploaded image to `localStorage` and use it to change `background-image` using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add to `localStorage` the user-uploaded image and use it as persistent background-image of the page.

I already have here the feature to upload and change the background, but not the ability to save it to localStorage.. What's the way to do it?

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
const frame = document.getElementById('frame');
const file = document.getElementById('file');
const reader = new FileReader();
const userUploadedBackground = document.getElementById('image');
const imgData = getBase64Image(userUploadedBackground);
localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);
reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
  frame.style.backgroundImage = `url(${ reader.result })`;
}, false);
file.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const image = this.files[0];
  if (image) reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}, false)
```

```css
#frame {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<input id='file' type='file' />
<div id='frame'></div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Would need more information to answer fully, but assuming you are referencing this for getBase64Image -- https://gist.github.com/colxi/c9ab898aa063e0943d4fae1840b982d8 -- then it looks like you are passing it a dom element, not a url, as a parameter.

Comment: That's just something I saw online.. but what I really want is to just save the uploaded image to localStorage and then load it as background-image everytime even after refresh. The upload/load is working already, but not the localStorage part..

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you would have to upload the photo somewhere and then store the url in local storage. Then you can load it using event listeners and apply to document.body.style in JS